# Field returning undefined when I use dot notation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am grabbing a specific document that contains an array, where each member of the array is an object that contains a userID field. When I just log the individual member I see the userID field but when I try and access just that field with object notation I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
const group = await Group.findById(groupID);
console.log(group.members[0]); //logs the object with a userID field
console.log(group.members[0].userID); //logs undefined
```

This is what `console.log(group.members[0])` outputs:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61be4e75ac29e62582fa1f67"),
  userID: '61be42d89dbaa49fa164774b',
  createdAt: '12/18/2021'
}
```

I tried using dot notation for the createdAt field and receive the same error.

Comment: yes, I can share the whole function if you think that would be helpful

Comment: Try group.members[0]["userID"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In my database, the group had the field userID, and in my schema it was userId.

Thanks to everyone who gave it a look, and in the future if you're in a similar spot make sure your schema matches up.